# Windows notification for WooCommerce orders

Tags: wordpress, windows, woocommerce, plugins

My site works with WooCommerce, I want to be notified in Windows when a new order is registered on my site, does anyone know how to do this?
Is there a plugin or system for this?

I use some plugins like New Order Notif, but this plugin only works in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Email Notifications:**
Most e-commerce platforms, including WooCommerce, provide email notifications for new orders by default. You can set up your email client on Windows to show notifications for new emails. This way, you will receive an email notification whenever a new order is placed.

**Desktop Notifications:**
Some web browsers, such as Google Chrome, allow websites to send desktop notifications. You can enable this feature in your browser settings for your WooCommerce admin area. When a new order is placed, you'll receive a desktop notification on your Windows system.

**Zapier**:
Zapier allows you to create automated workflows. You can set up a Zap that triggers when a new order is placed on your WooCommerce site and sends a notification to your Windows device using the available integrations.